# authorization_code from the response google

Tags: token, google-oauth, gmail-api

When I try to request for token after i get the oauth from google I am getting an error

```
 Response result body {
 "error" : "invalid_request",
 "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
 }
```

I know this issue is due to grant_type is not set properly that is authorization_code. But I am getting a response with code and other information when i request for oauth. My response comes as `authResult`. I am able to get the `authResult['code']` but when I try to get the `authResult['authorization_code']` it is getting as undefined. Can anyone out here help how to get the authorization_code from the authResult response.

My request for oauth:

```
 <span id="signinButton">
          <span
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="signinCallback"
            data-clientid="clientid"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"                
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
            data-response_type="code"
            data-redirect_uri="http://test-on.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Gmail_inbox">
          </span>
    </span>

     function signinCallback(authResult) {
          if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will not get authResult[authorization_code] just pass grant_type=authorization_code in your url. This will work for you.

Comment: I did the same this getting result as undefined.

Comment: can you please write the url which you are passing

Answer (score 0):

well i didn't get anything from your updated question but still i am writing here entire process of getting code and token.

1. make a http request  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http://test-on.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Gmail_inbox&response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline

Response you will get a code here and then

2.make a post request to get token 
 the url would be

code={YOUR_CODE}&redirect_uri=http://test-on.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Gmail_inbox&client_id={your-client-id}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&client_secret={your-client-secret}&grant_type=authorization_code

here you will get token tokens as a response

Comment: in 2.there is some change the link would be  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code={YOUR_CODE}&redirect_uri=http://test-on.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Gmail_inbox&client_id={your-client-id}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&client_secret={your-client-secret}&grant_type=authorization_code